# python pandas - .replace - nothing happens

Tags: python, pandas, replace

I have a df called `all_data` and within it a column called 'Neighborhood'. `all_data["Neighborhood"].head()` looks like

```
0       CollgCr
1       Veenker
2       CollgCr
3       Crawfor
4       NoRidge
```

I want to replace certain neighborhood names with 0, and others with 1 to get

```
0       1
1       1
2       1
3       0
4       1
```

So I did this:

```
all_data["Neighb_Good"] = all_data["Neighborhood"].copy().replace({'Neighborhood': {'StoneBr': 1, 'NrdigHt': 1,
                                                                                    'Veenker': 1, 'Somerst': 1,
                                                                                    'Timber': 1, 'CollgCr': 1,
                                                                                    'Blmngtn': 1, 'NoRidge': 1,
                                                                                    'Mitchel': 1, 'ClearCr': 1,
                                                                                    'ClearCr': 0, 'Crawfor': 0,
                                                                                    'SawyerW': 0, 'Gilbert': 0,
                                                                                    'Sawyer': 0, 'NPkVill': 0,
                                                                                    'NAmes': 0, 'NWAmes': 0,
                                                                                    'BrkSide': 0, 'MeadowV': 0,
                                                                                    'Edwards': 0, 'Blueste': 0,
                                                                                    'BrDale': 0, 'OldTown': 0,
                                                                                    'IDOTRR': 0, 'SWISU': 0,
                                                                                    }})
```

It doesn't give me an error, but nothing happens. Instead, `all_data["Neighb_Good"]` looks exactly like `all_data["Neighborhood"]`.

I've been trying to figure it out  for a while now and I swear I can't see what's the matter because I've used this same method yesterday on some other columns and it worked perfectly.

Comment: What about `all_data.replace` instaed `all_data["Neighborhood"].copy().replace` ?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. `all_data["Neighb_Good"] = all_data.replace({..})` ? Wouldn't that give me a new dataframe? I'd just like to get this new "Neighb_Good" column based on "Neighborhood" values and retain "Neighborhood" as it is.

Comment: I think `MaxU` answer ;)

Comment: True, that worked just fine. Thank you! I don't understand though why my attempt above wouldn't work. I've done many replacements that way yesterday. :S

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATE:** you seem to need [`Series.map()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html):

```
In [196]: df['Neighb_Good'] = df['Neighborhood'].map(d['Neighborhood'])

In [197]: df
Out[197]:
  Neighborhood  Neighb_Good
0      CollgCr            1
1      Veenker            1
2      CollgCr            1
3      Crawfor            0
4      NoRidge            1
```

using data set from comments:

```
In [201]: df["ExterQual_Good"] = df["ExterQual"].map(d)

In [202]: df
Out[202]:
  ExterQual  ExterQual_Good
0        TA               1
1        Fa               0
2        Gd               1
3        Po               0
4        Ex               1
```

---

**Old answer:**

Use [`DataFrame.replace()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html) instead of [`Series.replace()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.replace.html) if you have a nested dict, containing column names:

```
In [81]: df['Neighb_Good'] = df.replace(d)

In [82]: df
Out[82]:
  Neighborhood  Neighb_Good
0      CollgCr            1
1      Veenker            1
2      CollgCr            1
3      Crawfor            0
4      NoRidge            1
```

or use [`Series.replace()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.replace.html) with a flat (not nested dict):

```
In [85]: df['Neighb_Good'] = df['Neighborhood'].replace(d['Neighborhood'])

In [86]: df
Out[86]:
  Neighborhood  Neighb_Good
0      CollgCr            1
1      Veenker            1
2      CollgCr            1
3      Crawfor            0
4      NoRidge            1
```

Comment: I'm getting an error again. :( TypeError: Cannot compare types 'ndarray(dtype=int64)' and 'str'... for the following code: 

`d_excg = {'ExterCond': {'TA': 1, 'Gd': 1, 'Ex': 1, 'Po': 0, 'Fa': 0}}`

`all_data['ExterCond_Good'] = all_data.replace(d_excg)`

What can that be?

Comment: Ok I understand that it needs to be `d_excg = {'ExterCond': {'TA': 1, 'Gd': 1, 'Ex': 1, 'Po': 0, 'Fa': 0}}` and then 
`all_data['ExterCond_Good'] = all_data['ExterCond'].replace(d_excg)`. Thanks for help. This is kinda tricky, at least for a beginner like me.

Comment: Actually the above doesn't do it either. The values in the new column are again the same as in original. :( I'm completely lost.

Comment: @P.Prunesquallor, could you provide a reproducible data set? I've updated my answer - is that what you want?

Comment: yes sorry, here's a sample: `df = pd.DataFrame({'ExterQual': ["TA", "Fa", "Gd", "Po", "Ex"]})`
`d = {'Ex': 1, 'Gd': 1, 'TA': 1, 'Fa': 0, 'Po': 0}`
`df["ExterQual_Good"] = df["ExterQual"].replace(d["ExterQual"])` 

On that, I get _KeyError: 'ExterQual'_. :S

Comment: After seeing your updated answer, it works! THANK YOU. The problem was in the dictionary. Regarding my above comment, the following works: `df = pd.DataFrame({'ExterQual': ["TA", "Fa", "Gd", "Po", "Ex"]})`
`d = {'ExterQual': {'Ex': 1, 'Gd': 1, 'TA': 1, 'Fa': 0, 'Po': 0}}`
`df["ExterQual_Good"] = df["ExterQual"].map(d["ExterQual"])`. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
A   B   C
P   0   1   2
Q   3   4   5
R   6   7   8
S   9   10  11
T   12  13  14
U   15  16  17

data1.A.replace({0:"A"..and so on})
```